# How to set service_endpoints and delegation in subnet part of vnet in azure using terraform?

Tags: azure, postgresql, terraform

I have a working block of terraform vnet,subnet and NSG of it.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-vn"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "example-sn"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
  delegation {
    name = "fs"
    service_delegation {
      name = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"
      actions = [
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
      ]
    }
  }
}
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "example.postgres.database.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "example" {
  name                  = "exampleVnetZone.com"
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "example" {
  name                   = "example-psqlflexibleserver2022"
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location               = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version                = "13"
  delegated_subnet_id    = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  private_dns_zone_id    = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id
  administrator_login    = "postgres"
  administrator_password = "password@2020"
  zone                   = "1"

  storage_mb = 131072

  sku_name   = "GP_Standard_D2s_v3"
  depends_on = [azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.example]

}
```

But I am getting create nsg before subnet policy error, so changed the subnet creation as below.

```
# Create Virtual Network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "aksvnet" {
  name                = "aks-network"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/8"]

  subnet {
    name           = "aks-default-subnet"
    address_prefix = "10.240.0.0/16"
    security_group = azurerm_network_security_group.example.id
  }
  subnet {
    name           = "aks-postgres-subnet"
    address_prefix = "10.230.2.0/24"
    security_group = azurerm_network_security_group.example.id
    service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
       delegation {
     name = "fs"
     service_delegation {
       name = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"
       actions = [
         "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
       ]
     }
   }
  }

}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
  name                = "example-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  security_rule {
    name                       = "test123"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}
```

But getting below errors.

Please suggest how to fix that.

> ```
>  Error: Unsupported argument
> │
> │   on 11-virtual-network.tf line 17, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "aksvnet":
> │   17:     service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
> │
> │ An argument named "service_endpoints" is not expected here.
> ╵
> ╷
> │ Error: Unsupported block type
> │
> │   on 11-virtual-network.tf line 18, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "aksvnet":
> │   18:        delegation {
> │
> │ Blocks of type "delegation" are not expected here.
> ```

Even with below approach, I am getting policy error.

```
# Create Virtual Network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "aksvnet" {
  name                = "aks-network"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/8"]

  subnet {
    name           = "aks-default-subnet"
    address_prefix = "10.240.0.0/16"
    security_group = azurerm_network_security_group.example.id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
  name                = "example-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  security_rule {
    name                       = "test123"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "example" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {

  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.aksvnet.name
  name                 = "aks-postgres-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.230.2.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
  delegation {
    name = "fs"
    service_delegation {
      name = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"
      actions = [
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
      ]
    }
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_network.aksvnet, azurerm_network_security_group.example]
}
```

I am getting error as below.

> ```
> er-delete-dev"): network.SubnetsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error:
> ```
>
> Code="RequestDisallowedByPolicy" Message="Resource
> 'aks-postgres-subnet' was disallowed by policy. Policy identifiers:
> '[{"policyAssignment":{"name":"Deny-Subnet-Without-Nsg","id":"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/QSFT-landingzones/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/Deny-Subnet-Without-Nsg"},"policyDefinition":{"name":"Subnets
> should have a Network Security Group
> ","id":"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/QSFT/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/Deny-Subnet-Without-Nsg"}}]'."
> Target="aks-postgres-subnet"
> AdditionalInfo=[{"info":{"evaluationDetails":{"evaluatedExpressions":[{"expression":"type","expressionKind":"Field","expressionValue":"Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets","operator":"Equals","path":"type","result":"True","targetValue":"Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets"},{"expression":"Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/networkSecurityGroup.id","expressionKind":"Field","operator":"Exists","path":"properties.networkSecurityGroup.id","result":"True","targetValue":"false"}]},"policyAssignmentDisplayName":"Deny-Subnet-Without-Nsg","policyAssignmentId":"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/QSFT-landingzones/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/Deny-Subnet-Without-Nsg","policyAssignmentName":"Deny-Subnet-Without-Nsg","policyAssignmentScope":"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/QSFT-landingzones","policyDefinitionDisplayName":"Subnets
> should have a Network Security Group
> ","policyDefinitionEffect":"Deny","policyDefinitionId":"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/QSFT/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/Deny-Subnet-Without-Nsg","policyDefinitionName":"Deny-Subnet-Without-Nsg"},"type":"PolicyViolation"}]
> │
> │   with azurerm_subnet.example,
> │   on 11-virtual-network.tf line 37, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "example":
> │   37: resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {

Answer (score 1):

Check the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network#subnet) - if you create subnets within the `azurerm_virtual_network` resource, you cannot specify delegations or service endpoints.

I would suggest keeping your original code and working through the policy creation ordering issue.

Comment: The policy is applied in organization level, and can't disable that. could you Please let me know if any other options

Comment: is there anyway to apply service_delegation to a subnet after creating the subnet first? So that I would create subnet along with vnet and apply the delegation as separate block

Comment: Oh, I see your predicament now! Yeah, I'm not sure if there's a way around this I'm afraid, other than changing the management policy to an Audit action rather than a Deny. Maybe someone else will have an idea.